# Is there is a module like, "dbcm"?

Tags: 7, features, importing-exporting, deployment

Is there is a module like [dbcm](http://drupal.org/project/dbcm) in Drupal 7?

I want to know changes happen in database, so I can update my production sites with all configuration changes: new block, new views, new (CCK) fields.

I have tried the feature module to export my changes, but it doesn't export everything I need. There are also some configuration changes missed after exporting.

Is there a module that store in the database such configuration changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration management is a major initiative in the upcoming Drupal 8. [Here's Dries talking about it](http://buytaert.net/configuration-management-in-drupal-8).

In D7, you'll need [cTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) and [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) and [Strongarm](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/dec/04/strongarm-2-leaner-and-meaner/). And here's a [comparison of staging/deployment tools](http://drupal.org/node/980186).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [Activity](http://drupal.org/project/activity) module .... I could be wrong.

Comment: thanks,but I think this module make save changes happen by user like who add content or edit it,I am searching for a module that save any changes in database happen by super Admin like create new block or configure an old one

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried looking into features module http://drupal.org/project/features? I have used it in my D6 project which involved mutisites and multiple deployments on various servers. The module is worth to have a look! and will suit your requirements if you are in early stage of your project.

Hope it helps.

Cheers!